# My code is getting stuck in While loop (python)

Tags: python-3.x

I want the loop to check that the value y is integer or not after division if yes then exit loop if not contiune until it is but the it is getting stuck in the loop and I have no idea why, please help me.

Hers is my code :

`your text`

```
print("Welcome to Straircase Calculater")
print("")

print("")
x = float(input("Enter Floor Height = "))


riser = 15.0
y = x/riser
checkint = y.is_integer()

while checkint == False :
    riser += 0.1
    y = x/riser
    checkint = y.is_integer()


print("Number of Steps = " + str(y))
print("Step Riser = " + str(riser))
```

Comment: How about adding `if checkint: break`

Comment: What's the input you're entering?

Comment: This can't work. You are using floating point arithmetic for something that shouldn't use floats. The condition `y.is_integer()` is unlikely to be "reliably" true for any input, and very unlikely to be true for what one might consider the correct result. For instance `15.0 / (0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1) == 49.999999`, with `.is_integer()` being `False`, while `15.0 / 0.3 == 50.0`, with `is.integer()`being `true`. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

If you print out value of the riser, you will see something like this:

```bash
Welcome to Straircase Calculater


Enter Floor Height = 20
15.1
15.2
15.299999999999999
15.399999999999999
15.499999999999998
15.599999999999998
15.699999999999998
15.799999999999997
15.899999999999997
15.999999999999996
...
```

`15.999999999999996` is not an integer, so the while loop keeps going. This is a well-known and inherent [limitation of floating point arithmetic.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) If you want to achieve arbitrary precision with decimals, you can use use the [decimal library.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal)